# Dart - Do child classes inherit const constructors implicitly?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

The title says it. Here is a small example:

```
class Parent {
  const Parent();
}

class Child extends Parent{}
```

Does `Child` in this case have a `const` constructor implicitly, or do I need to define a `const` constructor explicitly?

Comment: 1. Classes don't inherit constructors. 2. A`const` constructor means that the object *can* be constructed as a `const` object, not that it must be.  Therefore there is no requirement that a derived class must also be `const`-constructible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by chance. I had a 3-level hierarchy of classes, and I defined a `const` constructor to the topmost parent. I left the (first) child class without defining a constructor. On the second child, I tried to define a `const` constructor, and I was notified with an error in the code - that its parent didn't have a `const` constructor.

```
class Parent {
  const Parent();
}

class Child extends Parent {}

class Grandchild extends Child {
  const Grandchild(); // shows an error
}
```

TL;DR: child classes need to explicitly define a `const` constructor, even if their parents already have one.